# Take filtered user input and make it correspond to a menu option

Tags: c++, methods, dictionary, user-input, calculator

I'm trying to build a simple one-operation calculator in order to practice techniques like `while` and `for` loops, and I'm trying to learn and understand ways to have "menus" in the console.

I've got a program that gives you a list (entries from `map`, a function I was able to use but know almost nothing about) of operations from which you must choose.

If you enter an invalid input (a non-integer or an out-of-range integer), it prompts you for a valid answer. Now I want the program to take the entries (1-4) and make them correspond to an operation.

You'll see in my code that each operation has its own method (I thought this would be a good way to do things, especially to practice working between methods). What I want is for `main` to take `operatorSelection`, and use that to choose which method to jump to. It will then compute `result` and return it to `main`.

I thought I might achieve that by using `map`, having `operatorSelection` correspond to an entry in `map`, and having that entry's corresponding string be used to call a method (where each method is named the same as in `map`).

**Note before answering**
I'm new to this and I want to know the optimized way to go about this. I want it simple, but efficient; I don't know some of the functions I'm using, especially `map`. I've read briefly about `vector` and `array`, but I didn't know how to make use of them. I realize `map` in my function seems to print in alphabetical order, and I'd like to be able to sort entries completely of my own preference. Is there a better way to go about this than with `map`?

Here is my code (the operation methods are incomplete, I know):

```
// OneOpCalc.cpp : Defines the entry pofloat for the console application.

#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int operatorSelection;
float firstNumber,secondNumber,result;

int main(float argc, char* argv[])
{
    bool validInput = false;

    map<string,int> Operations;
    Operations.insert(pair<string, int>("Addition", 1));
    Operations.insert(pair<string, int>("Division", 2));
    Operations.insert(pair<string, int>("Multiplication", 3));
    Operations.insert(pair<string, int>("Subtraction", 4));

    cout << "Welcome to OneOpCalc. ";

    while (!validInput)
    {
        cout << "Please select an operation by its number: ";
        cin >> operatorSelection;
        if (!cin || operatorSelection > 5 || operatorSelection < 1)
        {
            cout << "Error: Invalid entry. Try again." << endl << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else
        {
            validInput = true;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

float Addition (float firstNumber, float secondNumber)
{
    result=firstNumber+secondNumber;
    return (result);
}

float Subtraction (float firstNumber, float secondNumber)
{
    result=firstNumber-secondNumber;
    return (result);
}

float Multiplication (float firstNumber, float secondNumber)
{
    result=firstNumber*secondNumber;
    return (result);
}

float Division (float firstNumber, float secondNumber)
{
    result=firstNumber/secondNumber;
    return (result);
}
```

To put the question simply:
**What is a good way to call a method depending on user input?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: a `switch` would be appropriate (see below)

Other possibilities are:
A `map` with function pointers as *Ilya Kobelevskiy* has mentioned, or you use an `enum` for such a thing instead of the map, if you need all this at all (have a look at [enums](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/)). But first let's have a look at your code:

- You shouldn't use `float` as `argc` in your `main`. The argument count is a natural number, not a float (fracture).
- Don't forget your includes:

  ```
  #include <iostream> // for cin / cout
  #include <map>      // for the map
  #include <limits>   // for numeric_limits<...>
  ```
- Instead of `system("pause")` you should better use `std::cin.get()`. It has the same effect but it's portable and also doesn't *only* work under Windows.
- Instead of `!cin`, which is basically the same as `cin == null`, you probably want to use `!cin.good()`
- If you only have 4 operations, don't allow 5 as input (you currently allow it)
- Also, in your functions you're altering the global variable `result` which I think wasn't intented that way, was it? You can actually directly return the result without having to save it somewhere before.
- Global variables are somewhat [bad practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable). Try to avoid these.

Here is a working example of your code that also compiles:

```
#include "stdafx.h"     // inconvenient unportable windows stuff

#include <iostream>     // cin and cout
#include <map>          // the map
#include <limits>       // numeric_limits
#include <string>       // strings (obviously)
using namespace std;

int   operatorSelection;
float firstNumber,secondNumber,result;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    bool            validInput = false;
    map<string,int> Operations;

    Operations.insert(pair<string, int>("Addition",       1));
    Operations.insert(pair<string, int>("Division",       2));
    Operations.insert(pair<string, int>("Multiplication", 3));
    Operations.insert(pair<string, int>("Subtraction",    4));

    cout << "Welcome to OneOpCalc. ";

    while (!validInput)
    {
        cout << "Please select an operation by its number: ";
        cin  >> operatorSelection;
        if (!cin.good() || operatorSelection > 4 || operatorSelection < 1)
        {
            cout << "Error: Invalid entry. Try again." << endl << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else
        {
            validInput = true;
        }
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

float Addition (float firstNumber, float secondNumber)
{
    return firstNumber+secondNumber;
}

float Subtraction (float firstNumber, float secondNumber)
{
    return firstNumber-secondNumber;
}

float Multiplication (float firstNumber, float secondNumber)
{
    return firstNumber*secondNumber;
}

float Division (float firstNumber, float secondNumber)
{
    return firstNumber/secondNumber;
}
```

Here's a suggestion how your final program could look like. Of course there are still many things you could improve! (Just for example: Using classes and [OO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) code)

```
#include "stdafx.h"     // inconvenient unportable windows stuff

#include <iostream>     // cin and cout
#include <map>          // the map
#include <limits>       // numeric_limits
#include <string>       // strings (obviously)
#include <cmath>        // for NaN. ATTENTION: for gcc you have to compile with -lm

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int   operatorSelection;
    float firstNumber, secondNumber, result;

    cout << "Welcome to OneOpCalc. ";

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Please select an operation by its number: ";
        cin >> operatorSelection;
        if (!cin.good() || operatorSelection > 4 || operatorSelection < 1)
        {
            cout << "Error: Invalid entry. Try again." << endl << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    do
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cin >> firstNumber;
    } while(!cin.good());

    do
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cin >> secondNumber;
    } while(!cin.good());

    switch(operatorSelection)
    {
        case 1:
            result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            break;
        case 2:
            // don't devide by 0!
            if(secondNumber == 0.0)
            {
                result = NAN;
            }
            else
            {
                result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
            break;
        case 4:
            result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "I'm sorry, something went terribly wrong";
            return -1;
    }

    cout << "Your result is: " << result;

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Generally I can recommend to you this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/), especially the [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/) section. Also, feel free to google for more tutorials and try out the examples.

Another hint: If you don't want to use `stdafx.h`, then disable precompiled headers in the project properties. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261707/how-to-avoid-precompiled-headers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293538/precompiled-headers).

Comment: You're written so much and it's all so helpful, but I've been spending all morning trying to wrap my head around it. I replaced `system("pause")` with `cin.get()`, and it doesn't work-- The program now closes as soon as the `while` is satisfied. `!cin.good()` works, though with both that and `!cin` I've been trying to figure out how to get `OneOpCalc` to handle a blank entry as an erroneous input.

Comment: Accepting five inputs was an accident-- I'm building this program just so I can take the concepts I've learned and apply it to a preceding project where I need this concept, and there I have 5 options, so I must have forgotten to change that. Finally, **thank you** for pointing out the direct return concept-- This saves me quite a lot of hassle and hopefully I'll remember it for the future.

Comment: Also, I don't understand "for NaN. ATTENTION: for gcc you have to compile with -lm". Namely, the terms "gcc" and "-lm".

And lastly, I don't understand `switch` very well. You're telling it to go to any one of these five cases (including `default`), but I can't understand how it knows which case to use. Where is the condition? Or are the numbers following `case` just numbers by coincidence, and we're actually using my input to select the case?

(Sorry to leave you with more questions that pester)

Comment: replace `system("pause")` with `cin.ignore(); cin.get();`. For blanks for cin, have a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2624/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803502/c-detecting-enter-key-pressed-by-user). "gcc" is another compiler and "-lm" is a compiler option for that. If you don't use it, ignore it. For the rest of your questions: You *definitely* must get used to google your questions if you want to dive into programming! :) ... have fun!

Comment: I've been googling all day, and I'm used to it (it's like, 90% of my day regularly), it's just faster to ask a person directly sometimes. Thanks for everything, I'm much farther along than I was without you.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case ,it would be better to use a map of pointers to functions:

```
map<int,float (*)(float, float)> Operations;
Operations.insert(pair<int,float (*)(float, float)>(1, Addition));
Operations.insert(pair<int,float (*)(float, float)>(2, Division ));
Operations.insert(pair<int,float (*)(float, float)>(3, Multiplication));
Operations.insert(pair<int,float (*)(float, float)>(4, Subtraction));
```

This way you can simply call functions like

```
Operations[operatorSelection](0,1);
```

P.S. there are few typos in your code - should be float result = instead of result, maybe other...

In terms of efficiency though, a simple switch() statement would probably be the most efficient...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you indicate that I have typos; Could you rephrase it, perhaps?

Comment: I meant that code won't compile as you posted it, because it has syntax errors. For example, line (result=firstNumber-secondNumber;) should be (float result=firstNumber-secondNumber;). Take a look at answer of GT_mh, he provided working example of your code and went over the typos already.

Comment: Thank you, I'm reading and trying to understand his code now; Funny how `result` was completely superfluous, as it turns out.